Adding sequential numbers before duplicates in email
I'm currently learning awk and trying to normalize csv file. The result - send a scv file for processing and receive a new one scv.
I need to make all duplicate emails get a number before the @.
Source lines:
id,location_id,name,title,email,department
1,10,Sharon Petersen,Administrator,spetersen@email.com,
2,11,Sharon Petersen,Administrator,spetersen@email.com,
3,14,Andres Espinoza,"Manager, Commanding Officer",,
4,8,Elizabeth Feeney,CEO,e.feeney@gmail.org,Operations
5,8,Marilyn Baker-Venturini,Director,,

Expected lines:
id,location_id,name,title,email,department
1,10,Sharon Petersen,Administrator,spetersen1@email.com,
2,11,Sharon Petersen,Administrator,spetersen2@email.com,
3,14,Andres Espinoza,"Manager, Commanding Officer",aespinoza@email.com,
4,8,Elizabeth Feeney,CEO,efeeney@email.com,Operations
5,8,Marilyn Baker-Venturini,Director,mbaker-venturini@email.com,

I have already made few changes to normalize:

Capital letters for first and last names.
Ignoring commas inside double quote.
Create emails based on the first letter of first name and full last name. Sharon Petersen ---> spetersen@email.com

awk -v FPAT='([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")' -v OFS=',' '{ split($3,a," "); print $1 "," $2 "," toupper(substr(a[1], 1, 1)) substr(a[1], 2) " " toupper(substr(a[2], 1, 1)) substr(a[2], 2) "," $4 "," tolower(substr(a[1], 1, 1) substr(a[2], 1)) "@email.com" "," $6 }' file.csv


I haven't had success adding numbering of email duplicates to the current awk command line. =(
I partially managed to solve the issue using the awk -v FPAT='[^,]*|("([^"]|"")*")' -v OFS=',' '++arr1[$5]>1{$5=$5"-"(++arr[$5])}1' command, but I was unable to add numbering before @.
I really need advice. =)
Lots of articles and ready-made solutions.

Do email addresses that are not duplicates also get a number 1 inserted before the @ or are they left alone?

Emails without duplicates remain unchanged. Added some tricky positions from csv to the original post.

Now I'm trying to ignore the first line.

Given your updated input and requirements, here's how I'd really do everything you're trying to do using a 2-pass approach with GNU awk for FPAT:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk -v FPAT='[^,]*|("([^"]|"")*")' -v OFS=',' '
    NR == FNR {
        if ( FNR == 1 ) {
            for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
                f[$i] = i
            }
        }
        else {
            numSpaceSeps = split(tolower($(f["name"])), spaceSeps, " ")
            name = email = sep = ""
            for ( i=1; i<=numSpaceSeps; i++ ) {
                spaceSep = spaceSeps[i]
                email = ( i==1 ? substr(spaceSep,1,1) : email spaceSep )
                numHyphenSeps = split(spaceSep, hyphenSeps, "-")
                for ( j=1; j<=numHyphenSeps; j++ ) {
                    hyphenSep = hyphenSeps[j]
                    name = name sep toupper(substr(hyphenSep,1,1)) substr(hyphenSep,2)
                    sep = "-"
                }
                sep = " "
            }
            fnr2name[FNR] = name
            fnr2email[FNR] = email
            emailCnts[email]++
        }
        next
    }
    {
        if ( FNR > 1 ) {
            email = fnr2email[FNR]
            if ( emailCnts[email] > 1 ) {
                email = email (++order[email])
            }
            $(f["name"]) = fnr2name[FNR]
            $(f["email"]) = email "@email.com"
        }
        print
    }
' "$1" "$1"


$ ./tst.sh file
id,location_id,name,title,email,department
1,10,Sharon Petersen,Administrator,spetersen1@email.com,
2,11,Sharon Petersen,Administrator,spetersen2@email.com,
3,14,Andres Espinoza,"Manager, Commanding Officer",aespinoza@email.com,
4,8,Elizabeth Feeney,CEO,efeeney@email.com,Operations
5,8,Marilyn Baker-Venturini,Director,mbaker-venturini@email.com,

Unlike your original script, the above will handle:

name fields that include any number of middle names (John Jacob Smith)
Correctly upper-casing the first letter of each part of hyphenated names (Jon-bob walton-dude)
Hyphenated first and/or middle names (Sheryl-Ann Jones),
Multiply-hyphenated names (Bob The-Big-Cheese)
The name and/or email columns occurring in any order in the input as it just reads those strings from the header line to determine their position rather than hard-coding it, and
Escaped quotes within quoted fields (,"Manager, ""Commanding"" Officer",) courtesy of the improved FPAT value.

You may also want to take a look at What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?.

Original answer:
Here's a 2-pass approach, assuming that email addresses that are not duplicates do not get a number 1 inserted before the @, they are just left alone, and that the input isn't guaranteed to be sorted on the email address field and you want to retain the input order in the output (otherwise you probably wouldn't need a 2-pass approach):
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==FNR{tot[$5]++; next} tot[$5]>1{sub(/@/,++cnt[$5]"&",$5)} 1' file file
1,10,Sharon Petersen,Administrator,spetersen1@email.com,
2,11,Sharon Petersen,Administrator,spetersen2@email.com,

Set FS as you see fit to handle quoted fields, etc., I'm just showing how to handle the email field after you isolate it as you already do.

This really works. The script is interesting and allows me to learn where I made mistakes and how to use awk better. I really appreciate your help.

Assumptions:

file is not guaranteed to be sorted in any particular order
numbering for a unique address starts with 1 and is incremented +1 for each new occurrence
ordering of rows is to be maintained
OP's current awk script indicates we are going to overwrite/replace whatever's currently in the 5th field (email address)

Expanding OP's sample input:
$ cat file.csv
1,10,Sharon Petersen,Administrator,spetersen@email.com,
2,11,Sharon Petersen,Administrator,spetersen@email.com,
7,23,robert preston,Administrator,Robert_Preston@not_my_email.com,
9,72,sharon petersen,Administrator,sharonp@some_other_email.com,
10,41,robert preston,Administrator,robertp@google.com,
17,92,John Dough,Administrator,johnd@cakes_and_pies.com,

General approach:

determine the new name for the email address (eg, spetersen)
keep count of how many times we've seen a given name
update OP's current print to incorporate the new name and it's associated count

Modifying OP's current code:
awk -v FPAT='([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")' -v OFS=',' '
{ split($3,a," ")
  name=tolower(substr(a[1], 1, 1) substr(a[2], 1))
  count[name]++
  
  print $1 "," \
        $2 "," \
        toupper(substr(a[1], 1, 1)) substr(a[1], 2) " " toupper(substr(a[2], 1, 1)) substr(a[2], 2) "," \
        $4 "," \
        name count[name] "@email.com" "," \
        $6 
}
' file.csv

NOTE: we're not provided any sample inputs that would require the extensive FPAT definition so I'm merely cutting-n-pasting OP's code 'as is' (ie, I'm assuming this FPAT works as desired with OP's complete data set)
This generates:
1,10,Sharon Petersen,Administrator,spetersen1@email.com,
2,11,Sharon Petersen,Administrator,spetersen2@email.com,
7,23,Robert Preston,Administrator,rpreston1@email.com,
9,72,Sharon Petersen,Administrator,spetersen3@email.com,
10,41,Robert Preston,Administrator,rpreston2@email.com,
17,92,John Dough,Administrator,jdough1@email.com,           # unique but numbered


If unique (non-duplicated) email addresses are not to be numbered we can make a couple small changes to this code in conjunction with adding a 2nd pass through the input file:
awk -v FPAT='([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")' -v OFS=',' '
        { split($3,a," ")
          name=tolower(substr(a[1], 1, 1) substr(a[2], 1))
        }
FNR==NR { count[FNR]=++count[name]; next }
        { print $1 "," \
                $2 "," \
                toupper(substr(a[1], 1, 1)) substr(a[1], 2) " " toupper(substr(a[2], 1, 1)) substr(a[2], 2) "," \
                $4 "," \
                name (count[name]>1 ? count[FNR] : "") "@email.com" "," \
                $6
        }
' file.csv file.csv

NOTE: a single-pass solution is possible with some additional coding (to save all new rows in memory) while moving the print code to an END{} block (to loop through the rows saved in memory); will leave that to the OP to work on as desired
This generates:
1,10,Sharon Petersen,Administrator,spetersen1@email.com,
2,11,Sharon Petersen,Administrator,spetersen2@email.com,
7,23,Robert Preston,Administrator,rpreston1@email.com,
9,72,Sharon Petersen,Administrator,spetersen3@email.com,
10,41,Robert Preston,Administrator,rpreston2@email.com,
17,92,John Dough,Administrator,jdough@email.com,            # unique, no number

